# How to make the line fragments match up to single points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am currently trying to make a plot that shows before and after data of some ants based on site, however  ggplot keeps connecting all the points rather than doing it by unique site.

I've attached my code below, and a snippet of my data. I simply want one line fragment to connect two points.

```
  NumofAnts  Foodtype Trial
1         0 Pink.sum.     1
2         5 Pink.sum.     1
3         4 Pink.sum.     1
4         2 Pink.sum.     2
5        36 Pink.sum.     2
6         0 Pink.sum.     2
> 

`ggplot(winter_pre_post2, aes(x=Trial, y=NumofAnts, group=Foodtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Foodtype), size=4.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.1)) +
  geom_line(size=1, alpha=0.5, position=position_dodge(width=0.1)) +
  xlab('Trial') +
  ylab('Number of Ants')+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('Pink', "skyblue", "forestgreen", "yellow","red"), guide=FALSE) + 
  theme_bw()`
```

Comment: Hi @AnaRubio, I think I get what you are trying to plot. Where is the site information you mention?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question. But from my understanding, you are looking to connect points between Trial "1" and Trial "2", am I right ?

If so, I presume that values are paired (first value of trial 1 correspond to first value of trial 2, ...) but this is not implicite in your dataframe.

So, what I did is the following:

```r
Foodtype = rep("Pink.sums",6)
Trial = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3))
NumofAnts = c(0,5,4,2,36,0)
Connection = rep(1:3,2)

df = data.frame(NumofAnts = NumofAnts,Foodtype = Foodtype,Trial = Trial, Connection = Connection)
```

The dataframe looks like :

```r
> df
  NumofAnts  Foodtype Trial Connection
1         0 Pink.sums     1          1
2         5 Pink.sums     1          2
3         4 Pink.sums     1          3
4         2 Pink.sums     2          1
5        36 Pink.sums     2          2
6         0 Pink.sums     2          3
```

And now, you can plot them and add segments between each paired values:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(Trial), y=NumofAnts, group= interaction(Foodtype,as.factor(Connection)))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = as.factor(Connection))) +
  xlab('Trial') +
  ylab('Number of Ants')+
  theme_bw()
```

And you get :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get what you are looking for ;) Feel free to comment if you have any more questions